# What's the jquery-ui equivalent of jquery.tools's scrollable().navigator().autoscroll()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am converting a HTML template to rails 3 app.

The template is using jquery.tools.min.js which is not compatible with rails.js.
So I need to change it into using jquery-ui or some other plugins.

The current code is:

```
$("#slider_wrap #slider_container").scrollable({circular: true, speed: 1200, mousewheel: false}).navigator().autoscroll({
  interval: 20000       
});
```

This code doesn't work with jquery and jquery-ui.
What's the alternative?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: There is no scrollable widget in jQueryUI. However, it wouldn't be hard to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI, at this point, does not have an image slider/scroller.  You could, however, build your own using jQuery UI widgets.

If you don't want to write your own, then there are many many options out there for you to use (that are packaged as jQuery Plugins).

My Favorite one is the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).  It is pretty clean and easy to use.  [This](http://webdesignfan.com/jquery-slider-tutorials-and-plugins/) site has a lot of nice options listed for you too.

Hope this helps you out.